# When is this complex function differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)=z^a$ where a is a real number and $z$ is complex.

In what domain does $f(z)$ have a derivative?

I think if $a$ is an integer, then the function is entire, but what if $a$ is not a integer? Should I write it in the $\cos(\operatorname{arg}(z))+i(\sin(\operatorname{arg}(z))$ form and find conditions for which the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied?

Comment: How can you have a function without a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to address the problem of continuity before differentiability (which in this case is trivial once we have continuity). 
By definition, you have
\begin{align}
f(z) = z^a = \exp\left( a\log z \right) = \exp\left(a[\log|z|+i\arg z]\right)
\end{align}
but $\log z$ is not well defined on $\mathbb{C}$ since it's a multi-valued function. However, once we fix a branch of the $\log z$, then $z^a$ will be immediately defined and analytic on the domain where $\log z$ is define and continuous.